# Files not output to directory by webpack - publicPath not working

Tags: webpack, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-core-5.0, webpack-5

I have a simple `webpack` and trying to use `publicPath`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        jquery: './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    },
    output: {
       path: path.join(__dirname, '/wwwroot/dist/js/'),
       filename: '[name].build.js',
       publicPath: 'virtual-location'
    }
};
```

The file is placed in the `dist` folder and is browsable there :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/js/jquery.build.js"></script>
```

however when I try to browse `publicPath` - I get 404:

```
https://localhost:44306/virtual-location/jquery.build.js
```

And it does not matter whether I write it with folder slashes or not:

```
publicPath: 'virtual-location'
```

or

```
publicPath: '/virtual-location/'
```

Versions I use:

```
"jquery": "3.4.1",
"jquery-ui": "^1.13.1",
"webpack": "^5.72.1",
"webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
```

The output file look correct and do not present any errors.

Any idea why the built is not finding the file neither in physical nor virtual location?

Comment: Does [this github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1457) useful to you ?

Comment: No, it's a different case.